# passing checked checkbox value from one page to another page in php

Tags: php, html, sql

How to send the check box value from one page to another page in PHP? The checkbox value is fetched from database. i need to send the checked values from one page to another. Am new to php .

page1.php

```
<form method="post" action="setupstates.php">
  <table border=".3px" id='acttable'>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Act Name</b></td>
      <td colspan="5"><input type='text' name="actname" size="130" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Industry Type</b></td>
      <td colspan="5"><input type="checkbox">
        Select All Industries</td>
      <?php
                $conn = get_dbconnect();
                $sql1 = "SELECT*FROM industry";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                //echo $nrows;

                $sql = "SELECT name FROM industry"; //selection query
                $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); //odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
                // if(mysqli_num_rows($rs)>0){
                while ($nrows > 0) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
                        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='industrytype' value='" . $row['name'] . "'/>" . $row['name'];
                    }
                    $nrows = $nrows - 5;
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

page2.php( setupstates.php )

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Industry Type</b></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php print $_POST["industrytype"] ?>"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: make name as array industrytype[]

Comment: In the setupstates use $_POST['industrytype'] to get the value

Comment: where is your submit button in page1.php

Comment: after </table> tag am using submit button. its inside form

Comment: just print_r($_POST); on setupstates.php file and print here what are you getting? and why are you using $nrows = $nrows - 5; ?

Comment: The code you posted does not match the question you are asking. Your question indicates you want to pass a single value. Yet the code you posted has multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will work for you

```
 page1.php

    <form method="post" action="setupstates.php">
      <table border=".3px" id='acttable'>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Act Name</b></td>
          <td colspan="5"><input type='text' name="actname" size="130" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Industry Type</b></td>
          <td colspan="5"><input type="checkbox">
            Select All Industries</td>
          <?php
                    $conn = get_dbconnect();
                    $sql1 = "SELECT*FROM industry";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                    $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    //echo $nrows;

                    $sql = "SELECT name FROM industry"; //selection query
                    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); //odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
                    // if(mysqli_num_rows($rs)>0){
                    while ($nrows > 0) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
                            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='industrytype[]' value='" . $row['name'] . "'/>" . $row['name'];
                        }
                        $nrows = $nrows - 5;
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    ?>
        </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>


setupstates.php


<?php

if($_POST){
$chk = array();
$chk = $_POST['industrytype'];
$total = count($chk);
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){?>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $chk[$i] ?>"><?php echo $chk[$i]?>

<?php}}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code definitely works:-

Create first page- index.php

```html
<div>
    form action="process.php" method="post">
    <label>Select your interest :</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="Java"> Java
    <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="Php"> PHP
    <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="Python"> Python
    <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="JavaScript"> JavaScript
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

create second page- Process.php

```php
<?php
$course = (isset($_POST['course'])) ? $_POST['course'] : array(); ?>
<p><strong>Courses :</strong>
    <?php
    if (count($course) > 0) {
        foreach ($course as $course) {
            echo $skill . ' ';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No course has been selected";
    }
    ?>
</p>
```

Output:-Courses: Java PHP Python JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

You are passing multiple checkbox values, not one. This means that your setupdstates.php needs to be a loop to handle all the values.

Make note that checkboxes are weird. If you do not check it, nothing gets sent to PHP. So you will only get the ones that are checked.

```
<?php //page1.php ?>
<form method="post" action="setupstates.php">
    <table border=".3px" id='acttable'>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Act Name</b></td>
        <td colspan="5"><input type='text' name="actname" size="130" required></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Industry Type</b></td>
        <td colspan="5"><input type="checkbox">Select All Industries</td>
        <?php 
            $conn = get_dbconnect();
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM industry";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
            $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            //echo $nrows;

            $sql= "SELECT name FROM industry"; //selection query
            $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);//odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
            // if(mysqli_num_rows($rs)>0){
            $n = 0;
            while( $nrows > 0 ) {
                echo "<tr>";
                for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs); 
                    // 
                    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='industrytype[]' value='".$row['name']."' onclick=checkall();/>".$row['name'] . "</td>";
                }
                $nrows = $nrows-5;
                echo '</tr>';
            }    
        ?>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <?php // setupstates.php ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($_POST["industrytype"] as $value) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Industry Type</b></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php print $value; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: what is use of $nrows = $nrows-5; ?

Comment: total there are 18 checkbox value, to display 5 in each row am using $nrow.  $nrow is used for alignment only

Comment: Is there something about this answer that you do not like?

Comment: i just want to pass the checked values to another page

Comment: $_POST["industry type"] contains all the checked values from the previous page.

Comment: i need to pass the checked value from one page to another page